# Privatemsg & send email notify on new message drupal6

Tags: drupal-6, module, messaging, email

is there a way to make drupal6 Privatemsg moudle to notify user by email that he got new message?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in the Privatemsg module, this functionality is already there. You should go to (admin/settings/messages/notify) after installing privatemsg module.